# I get a Error from Heroku about Discord Intents (Discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm using Heroku to host my discord bot but I get an error saying

```
2021-05-22T13:49:05.066399+00:00 app[worker.1]: File "/app/Discord.py", line 6, in <module>
2021-05-22T13:49:05.066599+00:00 app[worker.1]: intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True)
2021-05-22T13:49:05.066604+00:00 app[worker.1]: AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'Intents'
```

and my code is

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
from kewl import *

intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$', intents=intents)
role = ""

# 290 lines of code

client.run(Token)
```

line 6 is this `intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True, presences=True)`

which is the problem, can someone help me with this, I'm new to Discord.py

Comment: Change the line 6 to: `discord.Intents.all()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to upgrade your discord.py version. This can be done by specifying the version you need in the `requirements.txt` file. You can check your version of discord.py by executing `discord.__version__` Latest version is `1.7.2` and putting this in the `requirements.txt` you would need to put `discord.py>=1.7.2`

If you want to use all the intents then it's best to use `discord.Intents.all()` instead of specifying the intents you want to use.

Comment: thanks looks like i had discord 1.3 added in my requirements